# PHP OOP, $this->var->method()?

Tags: php, oop

The typical way to use :

```
<?php

class A {
  public $var;

  public function __construct($var){
    $this->var = $var;
  }

  public function do_print(){
    print $this->var;
  }
}

?>

$obj = new A('Test');
$obj->do_print(); // Test
```

How can I implement something like:

```
$obj->var->method();
```

And why is this useful?

Comment: `$obj->var->method()` is not useful at all due to the meaningless example. `var` would have to be an object with a method() method. What you are likely looking for is http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=method+chaining+php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By making `var` an object of another class, you can chain the method calls to one another.

```
<?php
    class Foo {
        public $bar;
        public function __construct(Bar $bar) {
            $this->bar= $bar;
        }
    }

    class Bar {
        private $name;
        public function __construct($name) {
            $this->name = $name;
        }
        public function printName() {
            echo $this->name;
        }
    }

    $bar = new Bar('Bar');
    $bar2 = new Bar('Bar2');
    $foo = new Foo($bar);

    $foo->bar->printName(); // Will print 'Bar';
    $bar2->printName(); // Will print 'Bar2'
```

You can use this for neat things like [Dependency Injection](http://www.potstuck.com/2009/01/08/php-dependency-injection/)

Also, it **may** make your code bette readable and understandable because you don't have to *buffer* variables before making calls to their methods and can just call one method after the other.

Look at this example:

```
$obj = new MyObject();
$db = $obj->getDb();
$con = $db->getCon();
$stat = $con->getStat();
```

Which could be written like this using method chaining:

```
$obj = new Object();
$stat = $obj->getDB()->getCon()->getStat();
```

But, this is also harder to debug because if any of these methods throw an exception, you will just get the line number where the chain is, which can be quite a hazzle.

So, there are always two sides. It's just another style of programming.

Just be sure **not** to chain too long in a single line, as you will *definitely* lose overview.

**BAD**

```
$obj->meth('1', $arg2, array('arg2'))->method2($whaterver, array('text' => $bla_text))->andSoOn();
```

**GOOD**

```
$obj->meth('1', $arg2, array('arg2'))
    ->method2($whaterver, array('text' => $bla_text))
    ->andSoOn();
```

Comment: whether method chaining makes the code more readable is subject to debate. there is a lot of people who dont think so.

Comment: I, for one, think method-chaining looks much more readable. Why do you think the contrary @Gordon (if indeed you are against method-chaining for better readability)?

Comment: It depends on how you use it. As soon as you call the same chain twice, it would be bad from a performance POV at the least. But from the readability, I too can't really see much of a drawback... But I'm willing to learn!

Comment: It really depends on how you write it. Long chains (especially with arguments and written on one line) can easily get cumbersome to read because of many ->()$"', When I use chaining I prefer to lay out the chained method on a separate line each.

Comment: Okay, I agree with that. If you write everything in line, it makes your eyes bleed after the second time for sure. I'll add the note to the answer.

Comment: Don't Do meth() With Your Objects, Because They Might Die

Answer (score 2):

Your class could be something complicated, like a person that has an adress ( just like another class company could have one). Adress is a class in itself, so you'd want to call

```
$person->adress->makeLabel();
```

or

```
$company->adress->makeLabel():
```

You can implement this by making an object in your person (or company) class, just like a var:

```
Class Person{
  public $address;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->address = new address();

  }
 }
```