# What does $this mean in CakePHP?

Tags: php, oop, cakephp, this

I know that in Object Oriented Programming, $this refers to the current object. But in the code of the ArticlesController Class below,

```
public function index()
{
    $articles = $this->Articles->find('all');
    $this->set(compact('articles'));
}
```

'$this' seems to be referring to the class I want to use, which is the Articles class. I am very confused with what is going on. Can $this be used in this way too?

Comment: `Articles` is a property of the current object; it appears to be an instance of another object class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP OOP, $this->var->method()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290686/php-oop-this-var-method)

Comment: In PHP `$this` refers to the instance of the current object who's scope the code is executing in.

Comment: @miken32 Do you know about the CakePHP framework conventions?

Comment: Not a thing!!!!

Comment: @miken32 hehe then I think you are missing the point of the question. This question is about the CakePHP conventions, not PHP code itself. I'm fairly confident with PHP OOP,  and the $this->var->method question seems not to be related to this question. Thanks for your effort though :)

Comment: It's PHP. It doesn't matter what framework you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> '$this' seems to be referring to the class I want to use, which is the Articles class. Can $this be used in this way too?

`$this` does not referer to the `ArticlesTable` class, but `$this->Articles` does.

Your `ArticlesController` class has a property called `Articles` which is an instance of the `ArticlesTable` class.

Heres an example of how it might be done

```
class ArticlesController
{
    private $Articles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Articles = new ArticlesTable();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $articles = $this->Articles->find('all');
    }
}

class ArticlesTable
{
    public function find()
    {
        echo "find method called";
    }
}

$controller = new ArticlesController();
$controller->index();
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. So the  __construct() is called automatically even though I don't write it in code? If so, is there a way I can visually see all those automatic code?

Comment: @JAVAnewbie - Yes, `__construct()` is called when you initialize the class with `new ArticlesController()`. Every method in PHP that begins with `__` is a magic method, which is called automaticly by PHP, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php - My example is just that, an example. CakePHP is a big framework, so the only way to visually see all the automatic code, is to dig through the documentation or the code itself.